# How to add two radio buttons in a single row?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, bootstrap-4

I want to add two radio buttons in as single row with label, as shown in the photo, ow can I achieve this??

[image: requirement]

Answer (score 1):

here is the example how to solve your issue.

```css
label {
  display: block;
  color: #7d7d7d;
}

.floatBlock {
  margin: 0 1.81em 0 0;
}

.labelish {
    color:#7d7d7d;
    margin: 0;
}

.paymentOptions {
    border: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    break-before: always;
    margin: 0 0 3em 0;
}

#purchaseOrder {
    margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}
```

```html
 <p class="labelish">Payment Method:</p>
            <div id="paymentContainer" name="paymentContainer" class="paymentOptions">

                <div id="payCC" class="floatBlock">
                    <label for="paymentCC"> <input id="paymentCC" name="paymentType" type="radio" value="CREDIT_CARD" />  Credit Card  </label>
                </div>

                <div id="payInvoice" class="floatBlock">
                    <label for="paymentInv"> <input id="paymentInv" name="paymentType" type="radio" value="INVOICE" /> Invoice </label>
                </div>

                <div id="pay3rdParty" class="floatBlock">
                    <label for="payment3rd"> <input id="payment3rd" name="paymentType" type="radio" /> Third Party </label>
                </div>

            </div>
```

note: idea taken from codepen

Comment: Thank you @freelanceing mindset for help

Answer (score 0):

you need `display: flex;` for this:

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 16px;
}

.radio-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.radio-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="radio-container">
    <p>radios 1</p>
    <div class="radio-group">
      <label><input type="radio" name="group1" />radio 1</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="group1" />radio 2</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-container">
    <p>radioss 2</p>
    <div class="radio-group">
      <label><input type="radio" name="group2" />radio 1</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="group2" />radio 2</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-container">
    <p>radioss 3</p>
    <div class="radio-group">
      <label><input type="radio" name="group3" />radio 1</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="group3" />radio 2</label>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: clicks on Labels doesn't work....

Comment: oh sorry let me fix it, my bad

Comment: BTW you can group the inputs by giving the same name to them, maybe you want to select only one from all 6 inputs, if so give them all the same name

Comment: name ? did you read the doc?

Comment: yes name, and yeah I read the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#defining_a_radio_group)

Comment: oh, I thought clicks on radios don't work, I'm sorry. name for grouping and label need IDs

Comment: in the case here the use of id is useless, look how `freelanceing mindset` does in its answer...

Comment: thanks!, you're right, backend affected me I think... anyway I'll edit the question